# My word document have a line separation of half page. How can I solve it?

Tags: microsoft-word, text-editors, text-editing, text-formatting, microsoft-word-2016

In the document:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Wnd1lCcLVwRTWA_dCjWlZfWzjqGc7_g_/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=115679852586790547345&rtpof=true&sd=true

I have a huge line space, how can I fix it?

[image: huge space on image format]

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! Please post a screenshot of what you mean instead or in addition to the document itself, this way it is easier to understand what you ar asking and you will probably get a better answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have inserted a Section Break (Next Page). That's why your paragraph is jumping from one page to the other.

[image: Section break (Next Page)]

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> (or the button shown on the image below), to show the paragraph marks.

[image]

- Put the cursor before the section break, press <kbd>Delete</kbd>.

[image: Demo]

Comment: Is it possible to send me a screenshot that it indeed worked? For me, it is not working.

Comment: @JuanMuñoz See edit

Comment: I've had a similar issue and it's really a good approach.